# zoom and scroll image in WP7 in image control area

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

Is there any way or resource to do below task?
I am loading a local image in the Image control in xaml, wanted to enable zoom in/out but restrict the scaling limit to the Image control width and height.

I used this suggested approach [Zoom and scroll image in wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793239/zoom-and-scroll-image-in-wp7) in my app, but image scales to outside of the image control area and shadows other controls in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Image control itself, but in my zoomable canvas (based on regular canvas) I've used clip property. For ex.:

```
public partial class ZUICanvas : UserControl
    {

        public ZUICanvas()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FrameworkElement viewport;

#if(!LITE)
            viewport = this;
#else
            viewport = Viewport; //just another implementation
#endif
            viewport.SizeChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            viewport.Clip = new RectangleGeometry { Rect = new Rect(0, 0, viewport.ActualWidth, viewport.ActualHeight) };
        };

        }
//...
```